# Binary Relations - Simple Question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have the following binary relation:

> $x$ and $y$ have a common prime divisor

This binary relation $\textbf{is symmetric}$, but it is not reflexive and it is not transitive. Why is that? (This is what I have written in my notes.)

$\textbf{Reflexive}$

I thought this relation would be reflexive since $(x,x) \in R_\rho$. In other words, let's say $x=y=9$ such that we have the pair $(9,9)$. Then both $x$ and $y$ have a common prime divisor of $3$.

-

$\textbf{Symmetric}$

The relation is symmetric because we can have the pair $(6,9)$ and $(9,6)$. Both pairs have a common prime divisor of $3$. That makes sense to me.

-

$\textbf{Transitive}$

The relation is *not* transitive.

If we have the pair $(3,6)$ and the pair $(2,6)$, then transitivity implies there should exist the pair $(2,3)$. However, we know $(2,3)$ cannot exist because $2$ and $3$ do not share a common prime divisor. Thus, the relation is not transitive.

Comment: Is $1$ a prime? If not, is it true that $(1,1) \in R$?

Comment: Oh, duh! You're right. Thanks Dilip! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's not reflexive because (1,1) does not hold.